# zk + spring bean, null pointer for @resource

Tags: java, spring, zk

I have upgraded my application from zk 5.0 to zk 6.5 and spring bean is null after re-run application, please help, below is the code:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">

<description>Application</description>
<display-name>Application</display-name>
<!-- Spring -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring configuration -->
<!-- Initialize spring context -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- ZK -->
<listener>
    <description>ZK listener for cleanup when a session is destroyed</description>
    <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
   http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/core 
   http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/core/zkspring-core.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dc.myapplication"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:settings.properties"/>
<bean id="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="settings" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.path">${index.path}</prop>
            <prop key="max.hits">${max.hits}</prop>
            <prop key="search.resultsPerPage">${search.resultsPerPage}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

And @Component is defined below
CategoryServiceImpl.java:

```
package com.dc.myapplication.service.impl;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import com.dc.myapplication.domain.RfiCategory;
import com.dc.myapplication.service.CategoryService;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("categoryService")
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {
    @Resource JdbcTemplate dataSource;
    @Resource CategoryMapper categoryMapper;

    @Override
    public Iterable<? extends RfiCategory> getCategories() {
        return dataSource.query("SELECT * FROM category", categoryMapper);
    }
}
```

Below is where i use categoryService and nullpointer throw from categoryService.getCategories()
SearchController.java

```
package com.dc.myapplication.controller;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

public class SearchController extends AbstractController implements PaginationListener, RfiCategoryState {

    private static final String STATE = "state";

    @Resource CategoryService categoryService;

    @Override
    protected void initialise() {

        populateCategories();
    }

    private void populateCategories() {
        for (RfiCategory category : categoryService.getCategories()) {
            categories.appendChild(rfiCategoryRenderer.renderRadioSelector(category, this));
        }
    }
```

And i found that it works if i use
CategoryService categoryService = (CategoryService) SpringUtil.getBean("categoryService");
instead of @Resource CategoryService categoryService;

But i would like to keep my old code, Can someone tell me what went wrong in the old code, it was working in zk 5.0? It seems that the spring bean is ignored after zk is upgraded.

Comment: paste the stacktrace

Comment: What is your zk-spring version?

Comment: I didnt use zk-spring. I imported spring.jar version 2.5.6

Answer (score 0):

[Did you read the following manual](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Essentials/Chapter_9:_Spring_Integration#Register_Spring_Beans)?

You need to annotate the class with :

```
@VariableResolver(org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver.class)
```

and then :

```
@WireVariable
CategoryService categoryService;
```

Well, there is a dirty trick also (this is a base VM, but should work also for a controller):

```
public AbstractVM() {
    this.autowire(this);
}

protected final void autowire(Object object) {
    this.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
            .autowireBean(object);
    this.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
            .initializeBean(object, null);
}
```

And then you could still use the `@Inject`.
**Side note :** Please use this only as a quick fix and try to figure out what's the real problem behind the autowiring not working on some spare time.
I say this because the normal `@WireVariable` is the only best way to wire your spring beans.

**For finding out a solution:**

Try to change the `@Component` to `@Service` or `@Repository` and see if you still get a nullpointer, or drop the name given to it.
I know the documentation clearly speak about `@Component` but bugs are also possible.

Comment: I updated my SearchController to the below, still nullpointer exception.
@VariableResolver(org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver.class)
public class SearchController extends AbstractController
@WireVariable("categoryService") CategoryService categoryService;

It only works if i updated it to CategoryService categoryService = (CategoryService) SpringUtil.getBean("categoryService");

Can anyone help?

Comment: You misses the second listener in your web.xml as described in the link.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, I added both listener to web.xml. But still nullpointer exception.